# Combine multi-page PDFs into one PDF with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript

I am trying to use ImageMagick (6.8.0) to combine several multi-page PDFs into a single PDF. This command:

```
$ convert multi-page-1.pdf multi-page-2.pdf merged.pdf
```

Returns merged.pdf, which contains the **first** page of multi-page-1.pdf and the **first** page of multi-page-2.pdf.

This command:

```
$ convert multi-page-1.pdf[2] multi-page-2.pdf[2] merged.pdf
```

Returns merged.pdf, which contains the **third** page of multi-page-1.pdf and the **third** page of multi-page--2.pdf.

I would like to merged.pdf to contain all of the pages of each multi-page pdf. I have so far not found a way of telling the convert command to use a range of pages, although I have tried adding [0-1] and [0,1] at the end of the filenames.

Interestingly, this ghostscript command (which I found via StackOverflow but cannot re-find) does work as I would like it to:

```
$ gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=merged.pdf multi-page-1.pdf multi-page-2.pdf
```

The problem is, the ImageMagick 'convert' command takes urls as inputs and ghostscript does not, and I need my program to take url input rather than file paths.

**Is it possible to get the result of the above ghostscript command using ImageMagick?**

Comment: Just to point out, that when ImageMagick reads a vector PDF, it rasterizes it. If you then create a new PDF, it will be a raster image inside a vector shell and will be as large as the rasterized image. So what you want to do is not a good idea using ImageMagick.

Comment: This question is unfocused and goes off on a tangent about merging subpages when you're ultimately only asking about merging PDFs via URLs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I asked this question on an internal company forum, and the conclusion was that there is no way to do the type of document merging we would like to do with ImageMagick without first downloading the file the the local filesystem.

For those of you using Heroku, we are taking advantage of the Heroku 'tmp' directory in order to save the file "locally" on staging and production: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem

Once we save the file in 'tmp', we will iterate through each page of the pdf and save them all separately. We will find the number of PDF pages using the 'pdf-reader' gem.

EDIT:

Here is the custom paperclip processor I wrote to deal with this (all files are pulled down to the tmp directory beforehand):

https://gist.github.com/jessieay/5832466

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [`pdfunite`](https://www.unixblogger.com/how-to-easily-merge-pdf-documents-under-linux/)?

Example:

```sh
$ pdfunite 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf merged.pdf
```